# queryover and is in a list filter

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I dont really understand how I can perform this query using nhibernate queryover, I currently have:

```
var users= _session.QueryOver<User>().Future();

var comps = _session.QueryOver<UserCompetency>()
                .Where(x => users.Any(match => x.UserID == match.UserID)).Future();
```

an exception keeps getting thrown, using linq to sql this works perfectly fine?

Answer (score 0):

QueryOver is not LINQ. It does not support arbitrary expressions.

Use the `Query` extension method if that's what you need.